# OpenEdge read csv file with REST web service

Tags: rest, csv, progress-4gl, openedge

Hi guys (and girls)...

I'm wondering if it is possible to read in a csv file using a RESTful web service in Progress OpenEdge.

And if it can unzip the csv file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the file into a JSON object and pass it to the REST service.

On the server side you'd receive the JSON as LONGCHAR, convert it to a JSON again, extract the file from the JSON object, write it to disk somewhere and then unpack it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a CLOB to your REST service to pass in a file:

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttFile NO-UNDO
    FIELD FileData AS CLOB.
```

In the service, save the CLOB to a disk file:

```
COPY-LOB FROM OBJECT ttFile.FileData TO FILE "datafile.csv".
```

To unzip it, install the WinZip command line utilities. Wzunzip will unzip the file for you. 
http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/125/